# How to make sub figure referencing work in memoir + cleveref?

Tags: memoir, subfloats, cleveref, cross-referencing

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subtop[apple]{fig 100a\label{fig:100a}}\\
  \subtop[orange]{fig 100b\label{fig:100b}}
  \caption{Can you handle subfigures?}
  \label{fig:100}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:100a} and \namecref{fig:100b}.
\Cref{fig:100}
\end{document}
```

Both `\cref{fig:100a}` and `\namecref{fig:100b}` produce ??

The versions of packages used are: cleveref.sty 0.17.2 and memoir.cls v3.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should contact Toby Cubitt, the author of cleveref. He is very responsive to bug reports and the memoir support of cleveref is very new and little tested.

The problem is that memoir redefines `\label` within subfigures, so the cleveref version does not get used...

In the meantime, it's not pretty, but this works for your example at least:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subfigure}{fig.}{figs.}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Figure}{Figures}


\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\old@sf@@memsub@label=\sf@@memsub@label
\renewcommand*{\sf@@memsub@label}[1]{%
    \@bsphack%
    \old@sf@@memsub@label{#1}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{cref@#1}{{\cref@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack}
\makeatother


\chapter{Example}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subtop[apple]{fig 100a\label{fig:100a}}\\
  \subtop[orange]{fig 100b\label{fig:100b}}
  \caption{Can you handle subfigures?}
  \label{fig:100}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:100a} and \namecref{fig:100a}.
\Cref{fig:100}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My current workaround is to load `subfig` instead.

Comment: Has this problem been fixed in memoir and/or cleveref? I'm running into the same problem and considering that this issue first came up 1.5 years ago, I'm wondering whether I don't need to find a workaround. 

Nut

Comment: According to the changelog in the [manual](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex/cleveref.pdf) this should be fixed in v0.18.5 which is currently only available at Tony's own site.